# Preventing XXE Injection

Tags: web-application, xml

I've stumbled upon an exploit method which I haven't really had time to investigate before. **XML eXternal Entity** is said to be susceptible of a server-side type of injection. I can specify a Document Type Declaration (**DOCTYPE**) to define the structure of XML. Inside the DOCTYPE I can define entities and assign particular values to them. Then I can use the entities in the XML code and the parser will replace them with their values.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE doc[
  <!ENTITY pwd SYSTEM "file:///etc/passwd">
]>
<query>
  <name>Kiuhnm</name>
  <profession>&pwd;</profession>
</query>
```

So in which case I can read arbitrary files. My question is: is it possible to forge an XML-based patch or I should do this on server-level and disallow reading of files from the outside?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your library you should be able to configure your parser to ignore entities.

Comment: Could you provide an example or link me to something I can read more about this, please? SimpleXML, for instance.

Comment: You can find more exploitation and prevention information at https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XML_External_Entity_%28XXE%29_Processing

Comment: @wireghoul While this is a perfectly fine answer, the idea of StackExchange is to provide concise & complete answers: The etiquette suggests, that a definitive answer is  within your post. Use links just for reference and source attribution. Anyway, here's an upvote. :)